# mongodb upsert / addToSet / embedded Documents

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

My Document should look like this, one id does have up to 20 workCenters and each workCenter can have a few issues. Each workCenter array is closed or  blocked for further input as soon the id goes forward to the next workCenter.

```
{
  _id: "C7700258wcL4MSB050",
  WorkCenters: [
    {
      workCenter: "L4MSB050",
      Issues: [
        {
          issueType: "Material Movement",
          issueDuration: 14
        },
        {
          issueType: "Communication COA",
          issueDuration: 20
        },
        {
          issueType: "Lack of Tool",
          issueDuration: 12
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      workCenter: "L4MSB060",
      Issues: [
        {
          issueType: "Material Movement",
          issueDuration: 14
        },
        {
          issueType: "Communication COA",
          issueDuration: 20
        },
        {
          issueType: "Lack of Tool",
          issueDuration: 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I have so far now is:

```
TaktIssue.update({_id: centerId}, {$addToSet: {WorkCenters: {workCenter: workCenter, Issues: {issueType: issueType, issueDuration: minutes_2}}}});
```

Which is what I want...

```
{
  _id: "C7700254workCenter",
  WorkCenters: [
    {
      workCenter: "L4MSB010",
      Issues: {
        issueType: "Tech Error",
        issueDuration: 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but the 2nd entry for the same workCenter is a complete add to the first entry, and not just the issueType and time.
And a new workCenter does not add a new array.

```
   {
  _id: "C7700254workCenter",
  WorkCenters: [
    {
      workCenter: "L4MSB010",
      Issues: {
        issueType: "Tech Error",
        issueDuration: 0
      }
    },
    {
      workCenter: "L4MSB010",
      Issues: {
        issueType: "Lack of Tool",
        issueDuration: 0
      }
    },
    {
      workCenter: "L4MSB020",
      Issues: {
        issueType: "Material Movement",
        issueDuration: 0
      }
    },
    {
      workCenter: "L4MSB020",
      Issues: {
        issueType: "Tech Error",
        issueDuration: 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope its halfway clear what I like to accomplish.
Any Help or hint is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Actually it is **not** what you want at all. Note that `"Issues"` contains an "object" `{}` and not an array `[]`. And that alone should highlight the problem to you. Funny enough, just a few questions back from this: [Add Unique only to array and keep field count on update](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36119850/5031275), though for a different purpose, should at least give you pointers on the right direction.

Comment: I thought its a good idea :)  Maybe thats why I cant find informations how to do it like i want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `workcenters` document is empty as below

```
> db.workcenters.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56ef4f51fc6035db1abbf8ce"), "WorkCenters" : [ ] }
```

You can insert new `workcenter` through `$addToSet` with `$ne` as below

```
> db.workcenters.update({_id: ObjectId('56ef4f51fc6035db1abbf8ce'),
                        'WorkCenters.workCenter': {$ne: 'L4MSB010'}},
                       {$addToSet: {
                             WorkCenters: {
                                  workCenter: 'L4MSB010', 
                                  Issues: [{issueType: 'Tech Error', 
                                            issueDuration: 0}]}}})
```

Result is

```
> db.workcenters.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56ef4f51fc6035db1abbf8ce"), "WorkCenters" : [ { "workCenter" : "L4MSB010", "Issues" : [ { "issueType" : "Tech Error", "issueDuration" : 0 } ] } ] }
```

Then try to addd new `workcenter` to the existing `workcenter` with `$eq` as below

```
> db.workcenters.update({_id: ObjectId('56ef4f51fc6035db1abbf8ce'), 
                        'WorkCenters.workCenter': {$eq: 'L4MSB010'}},
                        {$addToSet: {
                             'WorkCenters.$.Issues': {
                                     issueType: 'Communication COA', 
                                     issueDuration: 0}}})
```

Result:

```
> db.workcenters.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56ef4f51fc6035db1abbf8ce"), "WorkCenters" : [ { "workCenter" : "L4MSB010", "Issues" : [ { "issueType" : "Tech Error", "issueDuration" : 0 }, { "issueType" : "Communication COA", "issueDuration" : 0 } ] } ] }
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much. But back to the first Comment, the kind I organized my documents, is it bad ? I dont know how to do it different. The documents wont grow a lot, may be in total just 800 at the end of the year. It is like one to many... One Machine has many WorkCenters has many issues. I have a second document were I store a summary of issues downtime and other things.